# Wordpress network gets redirected to main site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation hosted on a provider that is setup as a network. This Wordpress network has 2 sites, as follows:

- `/blog` (main site and first one created)
- `/blog/site1` (a second wordpress site in the network).

Both of these sites can be accessed via the same domain (`www.example.com`).

When a user tries to access the second site (`/blog/site1`) for the first time, the user gets instead redirected to the primary site (`/blog`). If the user types the URL of the second site and tries to access it again, then the correct wordpress site is displayed.

Does anyone know how configure wordpress not to redirect users to the main site by default?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use redirection plugin. You can get it in Dashboard> Plugins> redirect.

Comment: Feel free to advertise in your user profile, but please don't do it in answers.